# Python BeautifulSoup giving different results

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse an `xml` file using `BeautifulSoup`. Consider a sampleinpt `xml` file as follows:

```
<DOC>
<DOCNO>1</DOCNO>
....
</DOC>
<DOC>
<DOCNO>2</DOCNO>
....
</DOC>
...
```

This file consists for 130 `<DOC>` tags. However, when I tried to parse it using BeautifulSoup's `findAll` function, it retrieves a random number of tags (usually between 15 - 25) but never 130. The code I used was as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
z = open("filename").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(z, "lxml")
print len(soup.findAll('doc'))
#more code involving manipulation of results
```

Can anybody tell me what wrong am I doing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using the HTML parser; why not use `BeautifulSoup(z, 'xml')` instead?

Comment: use a different parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling BeautifulSoup to use the HTML parser provided by `lxml`. If you have an XML document, you should stick to the XML parser option:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(z, 'xml')
```

otherwise the parser will attempt to 'repair' the XML to fit HTML rules. XML parsing in BeautifulSoup is also handled by the `lxml` library.

Note that XML is *case sensitive* so you'll need to search for the `DOC` element now.

For XML documents it *may* be that the ElementTree API offered by `lxml` is more productive; it supports XPath queries for example, while BeautifulSoup does not.

However, from your sample it looks like there is no one *top level element*; it is as if your document consists of a whole series of XML documents instead. This makes your input *invalid*, and a parser may just stick to only parsing the first element as the top-level document instead.

Comment: I tried using the xml option originally, however, it shows 1 as the output and that's why I shifted to lxml

Comment: @AnotherCodingEnthusiast: It appears your document has no top-level XML tag, making it *invalid XML*. A parser can opt to only handle the first tag in that case.